# Any reason behind "static final Logger" field in singletons classes?

Tags: java

We have "private static final" instances of Log4j/commons logging in all service/utility classes (spring singleton beans.)

I am wondering if there is any reasonable case to have those objects "static final" if (1) there are no static methods that use it (2) classes are singletons?

I assume in either static instance or non-static property of a singleton objects - this would be the same old-gen object for JVM. Also I think JVM can easily identify an object if it is private and never changes for any performance purposes (if there are even any).

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I, personally always create a `private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger();` as the first line in ANY class I create (Spring beans, DAOs, inner classes, domain objects, etc). LogManager acts as a factory for my individual Logger objects:

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html

I follow this so much that my projects settings under Eclipse actually generates that line anytime I create a class.

When a logger is created, it references a name or a class to log under, the factory method I referenced above creates the logger with the specific class that it is contained in.

This practice becomes very useful when you want to adjust your log4j configuration. You can add highly or lowly qualified loggers at different levels or route to different files. There are a lot of possibilities for what you can do with the framework.

As for private static final, my reasoning for it are as follows:

- Because each class or subclass has it's own Logger, there's no need to share or inherit. Children may even be in a different upper package.
- Because Loggers are a class level type object, I always make them static. It makes it very clear that it has nothing to do with an instance of the Object of one can exist (for singletons, this may be redundant; but if the class is refactored, someone may do away with the singleton pattern and I don't see a negative to being explicit that this is a class property). An added benefit is that static construction happens when the class is first loaded (before it is ever initialized), so if I have a single bean which is a singleton the Logger would also be available in any of that classes static methods (regardless of any initialization of my bean).
- I choose to make mine final for the same reason, the Logger, from the time my class is loaded to when the JVM shuts down will always be the same thing for that class; mainly, it's reference to the log framework under that class.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thank you, so basically "private static final" is more of  a programmer's explicit intention to scope down the logging object and doesn't carry any technical/performance reason (apart from blocking unexpected behavior for inheritance cases, for example). That makes a lot of sense, cheers.

Comment: @serg.nechaev: There are technical and performance reasons mentioned in my post. Static construction takes place the first time the class is loaded via the ClassLoader, whether it is ever initialized to an instance or not. Final tells the compiler and JVM that for the duration of the Object from creation to destruction, it will point to the same instance (there are some memory advantages here).

Comment: Thanks mate, but can we really justfy these technical reasons" ? They are mostly theories that in performance area are normally guesses.
"Static constructors" do not carry none performance improvements. "Final" or not - is really an easy (to an extent) guess by JVM so really carries only semantic intent and nothing else.
As for memory advantages for static or final - what are they? They will still end up in old generation part of the heap memory...

Answer (score 1):

It's a common idiom to make the logger `static` and `final`, and it's easy to start a code review does the "standard" logger stanza appear. I would see no reason to deviate from the idiom in a singleton, but you are correct that it would only create one `logger` in the case of a singleton.